# Logging the web resources loaded by the ClientScriptManager in .NET

Tags: c#, resources

i am developing a collection of server custom controls, and i use resources like jQuery, jQueryUI and others.

I don't want to load the same resource more than once, so, i would like to know how to avoid that.

I load the resources like this:

```
ClientScriptManager manager;
```

`manager.RegisterClientScriptResource(this.GetType(), {{resource here}});`

It works, but i want to know how could i get the list of loaded resources, for avoiding the multiple loading.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cache header to avoid request for the same static resource/content from server.

Here's the article explaining the use and benefits of using the cache headers on static content:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581338/WebsiteplusPerformancepluswithplusASP-NETplus-plus